# Restoring a Gramps Corrupt Database (Berkeley Database)

Tags: database, berkeley-db, corrupt-data

I have tried to transfer my Gramps DB files from one computer to another but I keep getting the below error after even trying to break the lock of the database file:

```
    Gramps has detected a problem in opening the 'environment' of the
    underlying Berkeley database used to store this Family Tree. The most
    likely cause is that the database was created with an old version of the
    Berkeley database program, and you are now using a new version. It is
    quite likely that your database has not been changed by Gramps.
    If possible, you should revert to your old version of Gramps and its
    support software; export your database to XML; close the database; then
    upgrade again to this version of Gramps and import the XML file in an
    empty Family Tree. Alternatively, it may be possible to use the Berkeley
    database recovery tools.

    (-30973, 'BDB0087 DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery --
    BDB1544 process-private: unable to find environment')
```

I also tried to use db4.8_recover -c but failed.

**OS Name:** Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)

**Gramps Version:** 4.2.8

**Schema Version:** 17

**BDB Version:** 5.3.28

Could someone suggest a step-by-step solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have this issue?

Does any of the advice on the following [Recover corrupted family tree](https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Recover_corrupted_family_tree) page help?

If not open a bug report on the [Gramps bug tracker](https://gramps-project.org/bugs)

Ideally when moving between computers the recommended way is to [export](https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_make_a_backup) your family tree and [restore](https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_restore_a_backup) it.